# AWS Amplify: How to monitor data Transfer Out Per request?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm planning on using Aws amplify.

However, as per its pricing, it charges $0.20/GB as data transfer out charges.

So, As, my client is on a budget, I need to see how much data my react app is transferring per request.

How do I do that?

I tried to see Amplify analytics, But It fetched no results relating to Data transfer out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about Amplify Hosting, right?
There is a CloudWatch Metric called `BytesDownloaded` which according to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/access-logs.html#monitoring-with-cloudwatch) gives you:

> The total amount of data transferred out of your app (downloaded) in bytes by viewers for GET, HEAD, and OPTIONS requests.

Comment: Hey, another question, for example, if on graph, it shows: BytesDownloaded 441.57142857, So 441 byte is 0.000441 MB, so means if I receive 2,270,000, Requests,
Then 2,270,000 * 0.000441 is 1000 MB, Means then I'll get charged $0.20(For 1 GB data transfer out). Right?

Comment: please reply!!!!

Comment: you can also use the pricing calculator to get those numbers: https://calculator.aws/